# Boostrap 4 menu dropdown not showing completely using it in include

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I made a menu with bootstrap and php. It works fine but when I use it with an `include` in another php file the dropdown items are not seen. I don't know if I'm missing a `div` or should I use something else?

this is my menu.php code:

```
<body>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-secondary navbar-dark sticky-top">
   <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <!-- Brand/logo -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">Administracion</a>
         <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="ajuste.php">Ajuste Cota</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="estaciones.php">Estaciones</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="panel.php">Panel de Control</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="permisos.php">Permisos</a></div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">Medicion</a>
         <div class="dropdown-menu">
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Puesto 1</a>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Puesto 2</a>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Puesto 3</a>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>

</body>
```

and this is how I use this in another php file

```
<body>

 <?php include("menu.php");?>
<br>
<div class="container">
.
.
.
</body>
```

I should see the menu as follows:

menu.php:

[image]

But when I use menu.php in other file (as include) the menu item does not diplay

menu.php used as `include` file:

[image]

Can someone guide me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too many `<body>` tags...you should only have one set (`<body>...</body>`) in your whole page. You don't need them in the menu file if that's going to be included in another file.

Comment: ADyson thanks for the answer, I have 2 php files the lastone calls menu.php.

Comment: OK. So did removing the body tags from the menu file help? Maybe check and see if you have duplicated them anywhere else as well

Comment: If I delete the body it gives me an error. I think that when I select an option when displaying the menu the space should scroll down, to fit the new space (in menu.php). But I don't know if I can or how to do it.

Comment: What error, exactly? It's just some html.

Comment: It gave me a 500 error, I tried again and it didn't give me an error but it's still the same without showing the items.

Comment: Well a 500 error could mean anything - you'd need to check your PHP error log file to find out what that's about.

Comment: `I tried again`...so you did something slightly different, or what? You're being quite vague. Anyway if you removed the `<body>` and `</body>` from menu.php it's a step in the right direction. If you still have a problem with the menu not appearing, it could be something about bootstrap not loading or some other CSS conflicting, or anything reallly. We'd need a [mre] in your question to be able to diagnose it fully. I only answered based on the information available, and the certain knowledge that you cannot have `<body>` inside another `<body>` in your page - that is definitely a problem.

Comment: I just understood what you were telling me about the body and you were right. I made a complete new page with menu.php, removed everything and left only the menu and it worked there, thank you very much.